# How to call a phtml file after content (after form tag) on product details page

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to call a phtml file after content (form tag) on product details page. See the screenshot.

[image]

After this form I want to call a phtml file.

Answer (score 1):

In your local template either find the `catalog.xml` or a `local.xml` layout file and add the following

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="your.block.name" template="customefolder/demo.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now in the `catalog/product/view.phtml` you can call it where ever you want

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('your.block.name');
```

Comment: i used but it is displaying file content in between form tag.

Comment: <reference name="content">
<block before="content" type="core/template" name="demo" template="demo.phtml"/> i used like this it showing before from which is displaying before product info(just after header part)

Comment: That's correct. the `content` block starts just after the header. `product.info` should place it in the form if you call it there

Comment: can you pplease tell me how?with some code example.

Comment: I discribed exactly above what should be done

Comment: Don't use `<reference name="content">`, use `<reference name="product.info">` like the example from the answer says

Comment: @Sander  and @ 7ochem: firstly i used that one only what you wrote in answer but is it was not showing file content,after that i used 
 
<reference name="content"> <block before="content" type="core/template" name="demo" template="demo.phtml"/> then it is showing content but before product details.

Comment: what is the full path to demo.phtml?

Comment: customefolder/demo.phtml

Comment: @Urvashi updated my answer. In that case the value of `template` needs to be `customefolder/demo.phtml ` for Magento to understand where it's located

Comment: Thanks i will try.I have one doubt if this demo file is of some extension then also we can call like this?

Comment: Exactly, always specify the full path startming from the `template` directory

Comment: it is not working,if i call the code i mansion above<see comment> in that extension.xml then only it is displaying  before product details.otherwise it is not displaying that file content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28980/discussion-between-urvashi-and-sander-mangel).